# Tesseract-OCR on Heroku with Node.js

Tags: heroku, ocr, tesseract

is there any possibilities to use Tesseract-OCR on Heroku with Node.js ?

I read somewhere that gcc is needed and is not available on Heroku...
Maybe it's possible to compile it locally before upload?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Tesseract with Node.js or with JavaScript in the browser: [tesseract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#tesseractjs)

It can be directly used as a node-dependency or be used in the browser using either CDNs or a packaging tool like webpack (all described in more detail in the linked project).